# Cannot call value of non-function type 'AVAudioPlayer'

Tags: swift

I keep looking over my cade and can't seem to find what the problem is. Here is the code.

```
@IBAction func PlayAudio(sender: AnyObject) {
    let AVAudioPlayer = ButtonAudioPlayer{
        ButtonAudioPlayer.play()
}
```

It just throws out the error that says "Cannot call value of non-function type 'AVAudioPlayer'"

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use `AVAudioPlayer` (capitalized) as a constant name. That name [is already defined as a class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/).

Make it more like:

```
let myAudioPlayer = ButtonAudioPlayer{
    ButtonAudioPlayer.play()
    // etc.
```

Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
let audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = ButtonAudioPlayer{
```

Comment: A comment or correction of any error or inaccuracy would be welcome :)